# matplotlib plotting multiple lines

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

Consider the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from regressors import stats
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

def read_data() -> pd.DataFrame:
    data = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='./Boston.csv')
    data = data.dropna()

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.drop(columns=df.columns[0], inplace=True)

    return df

BOSTON: pd.DataFrame = read_data()

def part_a(plot: bool = False) -> None:
    X: np.ndarray = BOSTON[['dis']].values
    y: np.ndarray = BOSTON['nox']

    poly: PolynomialFeatures = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3, include_bias=False)
    X_poly: np.ndarray = poly.fit_transform(X=X)

    model: LinearRegression = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X=X_poly, y=y)

    stats.summary(clf=model, X=X_poly, y=y, xlabels=poly.get_feature_names_out(input_features=['dis']))

    if plot:
        y_pred = model.predict(X=X_poly)

        plt.title('nox vs. dis')
        plt.scatter(x=X, y=y, color='blue', marker='o', facecolors='none', label='Observed')
        plt.plot(X, y_pred, color='red')
        plt.xlabel('dis')
        plt.ylabel('nox')
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()

part_a(plot=True)
```

It plots the following:

[image]

Why are there multiple red lines?

Comment: Inspect your `X` vector. It is probably in the wrong order so the line is 'jumping' around.

Comment: `xs = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), 500); y_pred = model.predict(X=xs); plt.plot(xs, y_pred)`